# Analyzing logical form

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

$$x\in \cap_{i\in I}(A_i\cup B_i)$$

I'm trying to analyze the logical form of this statement. First, what does it really mean to "analyze the logical form"? It would be more clear if it was just the intersection of the $A_i$, but what's inside the brackets is throwing me off. If someone could show me the right direction to take I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "analyze the logical form" means to describe in a rigorous fashion what the symbols given mean. Or in other words, what are the semantics of this given syntax.

$$x \in \cap_{i \in I}(A_i \cup B_i)  \\ \iff \\ x \in \cap_{i\in I}\{ y : y \in A_i \text{ or } y \in B_i\} \\ \iff \\ x\in \{y: y \in \{ z : z \in A_i \text{ or } z \in B_i\}\  \forall i \in I\} $$

Which is equivalent to
$$x \in \{ y : \forall i \in I, y \in A_i \text{ or } y \in B_i\}$$ as pointed out in the comment by Dan Vellerman.

Or in words:

$x$ is a variable such that it is in every set formed by taking the union of the two sets $A_i$ and $B_i$ where $i$ is an element of the set of indices for the aforementioned sets.

Comment: This answer can be simplified quite a bit.  First of all, $y \in \{z : z \in A_i \text{ or } z \in B_i\}$ means the same thing as $y \in A_i$ or $y \in B_i$.  So that simplifies the answer to:  $x \in \{y : y \in A_i \text{ or } y \in B_i, \forall i \in I\}$.  And then that can be simplified further to $x \in A_i$ or $x \in B_i$, $\forall i \in I$.  Most people would put the quantifier first, like this:  $\forall i \in I$, $x \in A_i$ or $x \in B_i$.

Comment: Yes that is a good point. I wanted to unpack it for the OP to make clear the nesting behaviour.  And, yes often people place the quantifiers first

Comment: @Dan Velleman oliverjones Is $\exists x(\forall i\in I(x\in A_i \lor x\in B_i))$ an acceptable way to write this?

Comment: The given statement doesn't include any information about the existence of such an $x$. We would need $$\exists x \in \cap_{i \in I}(A_i \cup B_i).$$

Comment: @oliverjones so simply $ x(\forall i\in I(x\in A_i \lor x\in B_i))$? To me that says the same thing as the original statement.

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: @fmtcs Get rid of the $x$ at the beginning.  It should just be $\forall i \in I(x \in A_i \vee x \in B_i)$.